# Initializing hash with default value and incrementing by 1

Tags: ruby, hash

I need a hash whose keys should have default value 0. (basically I'm making a counter). Keys are not known so I cannot initialize them in beginning. Also with every occurrence of the key, the value should increase by 1.

I have come up with this:

```
hash = {}
hash[key] ? hash[key]+=1 : hash[key]=0
```

This looks OK and short, but I don't like repeating `hash[key]` so many times in one line of code. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think all you need is to give the hash a default value of `0`

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
```

then for every occurrence of the key, you don't need to check its value, just increment it directly:

```
hash[key]+=1
```

Reference: [`Hash#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Comment: okey i upvote because it the same as my answer, just other way )

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`Hash#default`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D):

```
=> h = { }
=> h.default = 0
=> h["a"]
#> 0     
=> h["z"]
#> 0
```

Comment: I tried using default. Somehow it was not working. I tried it this way: `h.default(0)`. Your example seems to work though. Thanks

Comment: this `h.default(0)` not the same as `h.default = 0`.

Comment: can you explain how are they different? Im on ruby 1.8.7 and I re-checked. `h.default(0)` is not working but `h.default = 0` is.

Comment: this is different things. why this `foo = 's'` works but this `foo('s')` no?

Comment: `h.default(0)` calls the `default` with an argument of `0`. But the `default` method doesn't take an argument. `h.default = 0` calls the `default=` method with an argument of `0`. The `default=` method *does* take an argument. Basically, you are calling two completely different methods, why would you even expect them to do the same thing?